# Prove inequality using Lagrange's remainder

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion, absolute-value

My problem is the following:

Prove that $\left | e^{x}+e^{-x}-2-x^{2} \right |\leq \frac{1}{6}x^{4}$ when $\left | x \right|\leq1$.

Using Maclaurin's expansion formula, I get that

$$e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+x^{4}\frac{e^{\Theta_1x}}{24},0\leq\Theta_1\leq1$$
$$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{6}+x^{4}\frac{e^{-\Theta_2x}}{24},0\leq\Theta_2\leq1$$

I can now simplify the inequality to:
$$\left | x^{4}\frac{e^{\Theta_1x}}{24}+x^{4}\frac{e^{-\Theta_2x}}{24} \right |=\frac{x^{4}}{24}\left | (e^{\Theta_1x}+e^{-\Theta_2x}) \right |\leq \frac{1}{6}x^{4}\Leftrightarrow\frac{x^{4}}{4}\left | (e^{\Theta_1x}+e^{-\Theta_2x}) \right |\leq x^{4}$$

Aaaand here I'm pretty much stuck. What am I supposed to do here? I guess I have to find something in between my LHS and my RHS and then prove that that thing is less than my RHS. Thankful for help!

Comment: @operatorerror So I can use that $e+1<4$ to get that $\frac{x^{4}}{4}\left | (e^{\Theta_1x}-e^{-\Theta_2x}) \right |\leq\frac{x^{4}}{e+1}\left | (e^{\Theta_1x}-e^{-\Theta_2x}) \right |$? Where do I go now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a mistaken sign here:
$$e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{6}\color{red}{+}x^{4}\frac{e^{-\Theta_2x}}{24},0\leq\Theta_2\leq1$$
Next, since the inequality is even (i.e. unchanged by the substitution $x\mapsto -x$), you can assume $x\ge 0$. The left-hand side becomes
$$\frac{x^4}{24}\left | e^{\Theta_1x}+e^{-\Theta_2x} \right |=\frac{x^4}{24}\left(e^{\Theta_1x}+e^{-\Theta_2x}\right) $$ We have
$$e^{\Theta_1x}\le e^1<3\\e^{-\Theta_2x}\leq e^0=1\\\Rightarrow e^{\Theta_1x}+e^{-\Theta_2x} < 4 $$
and you can conclude. Note that this also shows the expression inside the absolute value is non-negative.

Comment: Oh yeah now I understand! Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanAxelsson After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).